# Inner structure of a bipolar stepper motor?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, stepper-motor, coil, bipolar

The classic diagram looks like this with coils just positioned sideways to the rotation

[image]

I'm not sure if this is just a schematic or it indicates the actual structure. However I assume the actual structure is more like this

[image]

This makes more sense in terms of lining up the motor with more precision, although the first (sideways coil) setup should still be able to control a magnet with a bit more effort.

But finally looking up the actual stepper inside I see this.

[image]

How can 4 wires control so many coils. Can someone help me understand what's going on here.

Thanks

Comment: top/bottom and left/right are energized  .... the diagonals are the other phase .... look at the alignment of the rotor and stator teeth .... the diagonals are the next closest alignment

Comment: here is a video ... https://youtu.be/Qc8zcst2blU?t=1829 .... better one here https://youtu.be/eyqwLiowZiU?t=155

Answer (score 1):

There are 200 Full Steps/Rev with 4 Stator Pole pairs and 50 Rotor magnet Poles

[image]

The 4 wire motors must use 4 Half or 2 Full bridges to provide bipolar Currents. Phases may be half,quarter or microstepped with less torque but smaller, smoother angle steps.

Comment: So each pair of while controls 4 poles? Does that mean that 2 separate coils are always in sync?

Comment: Yes. While top and bottom are lined up to attract teeth while the horizontal ones on the same current are wired to repel teeth and attract between the teeth ( opposite magnetic polarity). Then the other coil pair can either rotate CW or CCW depending wire pair polarity by 360/200 step angle,  or 1.8 deg.  There are many variations in windings. Series, Parallel, 5 wire, 6, 8 wire etc